# UTF8 correct text but being saved incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have UTF-8 MySql DB and it was never problem to display something inside browser
But I face the problem when trying to save UTF8 data into a file (or transfer it via force download).
All non-lating charachters being displayed incorrectly (no matter what encoding I switch)
just fyi: that part of the text is hebrew.

What I tried so far and failed:

- `set names 'utf-8'`
- setting `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')`
- `utf8_encode` on part of the string or fully on whole text
- putting `fwrite($f, pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf));` (yes, files being recognized as utf8, but symbols still incorrect)

The most frustrating thing is browser shows it correctly all the time
Any ideas, gents?

PS: this is how I send file to force download:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=xml_invoices.xml');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($xml_file));
echo $xml_file; //this string contains latin and non-latin charachters
exit();
```

Comment: How exactly are you *testing* that it's "saved incorrectly"‽ Encodings require two parties: one to *write* correctly and one to *read* correctly.

Comment: well I just fwrite to the file and that's it. As for reading - I tried almost every possible encoding in text editor and it doesnt show correct symbols. (I also tested windows-1255, which is hebrew)

Comment: So you're opening the file in a text editor... How exactly are you ensuring it's reading the file correctly? Maybe try a hex editor instead and show us the raw content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple days of research I found that you need few things to solve encoding problems:

- be sure you are using viewer that can display different encodings (force change encoding for file if needed), pretty much sure every IDE can do that.
- be sure what encoding you are having troubles with (my case was windows-1255)
- experiment with iconv() function to convert parts of the text you are having problems with.

So after all it turned that F4 viewer AkelPad didnt display hebrew symbols at all.
Good luck guys!

Answer (score 0):

Likely you want to change the charset of the connection. Either issue a `SET NAMES 'UTF-8'` after connecting or, if using PDO, appending the charset configuration `charset=utf8` to the connection string.

This is necessary because the client transcodes text columns' contents after retrieving the byte stream from the server, and transcoding is from the column encoding to the client charset, so [you must override it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html).

Just to be sure, double check that the encoding of the relevant columns is able to store your characters (for example some unicode scheme like UTF-8) and that the text is stored correctly (check from MySQL workbench or some other client than your application)

Comment: used that already and failed, set names is not necessary in my case because as I explained browser pages works fine with that text